# Schematic review for simple LED circuit?

Tags: led, diodes, schematics, schmitt-trigger

I'm pretty new to circuit design, I am trying to make a small board with a few LEDS that uses a toggle to turn on and another toggle to either show the LEDS always on or to blink the LEDS.  I believe that this circuit will work as the `CD74AC14` schmitt-trigger IC is low power (1.5 - 5V) and the LEDS are being driven at about 1.7V.
For 11 LEDS @ ~20mA each its about 385mA-hours.

I am thinking a coin cell rated at 3.0V , probably a `Panasonic BR-2477A/FBN` ?

If there are any pointers or critiques please let me know. 
[image]

Datasheet for Switch : http://www.ckswitches.com/media/1422/js.pdf

EDIT : Updated schematic to fix switch issue. LEDS left as is.

Comment: coin cells have really high internal resistance and would not manage such a high current draw

Comment: Those are really weird symbols you've used for the switches.  I have no idea which terminals are connected under what conditions.

Comment: @Makoto That's a shame, is there a small battery you could recommend?    @ Peter That was what the data sheet used, I've never seen it either. Pins across from each other are connected (6 to 3, etc)

Comment: If those are 2K2 resistors, the current in each LED will be about 0.5 mA, or a total of 6 mA.  It is generally considered bad practice to connect LEDs in parallel as you have shown, as they will not be perfectly matched, so one (or some) will be lower voltage than others, so will draw more current, be brighter, get warmer, LED voltage drops with rising temperature, so those drawing more current will draw even more current....

Comment: Please give a link to the switch datasheet so we can (hopefully) figure out what it really means.

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes they are 2K2. Oh, I had no idea. I don't think I can put them in series if I am trying to  toggle their driver though, can I?  Here is the link for the datasheet http://www.ckswitches.com/media/1422/js.pdf  . Its the JS202011SCQN

Comment: Those switches are DPDT (Double Pole, Double Throw) - Terminals 1, 2, and 3 are one pole, and 4, 5, 6 are the other.  In one position, terminals 1 and 2 are connected, as are 4 and 5.  In the other position, 2 and 3 are connected, as are 5 and 6.  As you have shown the switch wiring, nothing will work.  Your drawing doesn't show the rectangular boxes shown on the datasheet, which represent the moving contacts.

Comment: So then if I put VDD on terminal 4 and connect another wire to terminal 5, it will act as a power toggle? On in one position and off in the other position? Passing VDD to terminal 5 only in one position?

Comment: Terminal 5 of the switch is the "Common" terminal of one pole, and will be connected to eithere 4 or 6, depending on the switch position.

Comment: I've fixed the switches not working, as for the LEDS, if I put them in series won't I need a big battery? Will matching the trace lengths not help with the matching?

Comment: The problem with the LEDs is the connection tying all the LED cathodes together.  Connecting several LED-plus-resistor pairs in parallel is fine.

Comment: @PeterBennett Any recommendations besides using 11 caps to connect to the LEDs from pin 4 of the `CD74AC14` ?

Comment: First, get rid of C2. Second isolate each of the LED/2.2k resistor pairs. Third, connect all 5 of the 74AC gates which drive outputs to the first (the one using pins 1 and 2). Fourth, trace length is irrelevant in this case. Fifth, as mentioned a coin cell is not a good idea - use something bigger, with a voltage of more than 3 volts.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast As shown the drive with 2 separate phases of gates plus C@ is aimed at voltage doubling. When gates BCD are low then gates EF are high and you get 2 x Vout via C2 to give a current pulse. Removing C2 and going to single ended drive needs more V and/but is nicer overall.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Good pointers, but I really need this to be a low voltage device. I don't really want to use an N cell but I think I might have to. I want to make this a small form factor device.